# How to fetch Json array data in android studio using volley?

Tags: android, arrays, json, sorting

I have a JSON encode array given bellow:-

```
{
"imager": [{
    "title": "Guru",
    "images": ["images\/6.png", "images\/androidIntro.png", "images\/barretr_Earth.png"]
}]
```

}

My Problem is that I want to fetch all the images from images array one by one so that I can show the images on imageview. my Main aim is to display Title only one time and show all the images related to the title, I have searched all over the internet and stackflow but I am unable to find the proper answer 
could anyone help me solving this?
I am using Volley Libabry here is my code:-

```
  url = "myurl";

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {


                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("imager");

                for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = object.getString("title");
                    String images = object.getString("images");

                   // what to do here now?? help me?
                }
```

if I set

```
textview.setText(images);
output will be like this:-
["images\/6.png","images\/androidIntro.png","images\/barretr_Earth.png"]
```

but i want only
images/6.png
images/androidIntro.png
images/battetr_Earth.png

So that I can so these all images in imageview.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the `"images"` tag as an array.

Instead of

```
String images = object.getString("images");
```

use

```
JsonArray images = object.getJSONArray("images");
for (int j=0; j<images.length(); j++) {
    String image = images.getString(j)
    // image will be 
    // j = 0 -> "images\/6.png"
    // j = 1 -> "images\/androidIntro.png"
    // j = 2 -> "images\/barretr_Earth.png"
}
```

Comment: I have done this part, with your help thank you for that but now I am facing another problem, I am getting all the images correct and titles too but the problem is that  I am getting multiple titles like this {image: images/6.png title: guru} {image: images/androidIntro.png title: guru} {image: images/barretr_Earth.png title: guru} i just want title to display only one time

Comment: Simple don't display the title inside the second for.